# Compute $\int\frac{1}{(1+x^n)\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How to compute this integral:$$\int\frac{1}{(1+x^n)\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}}dx$$I tried to make$$\ t^n = 1+x^n$$ But I got a more complicated formula$$\int\frac{1}{t^{n+1}}\frac{t^{n-1}}{{(t^n-1)}^\frac{n-1}{n}}dt$$then I can not go on

Comment: Just as a hint, Chebyshev's theorem here(https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials), states that your integral has solution in elementary functions, only in these case 1)$n=1$ 2) $n=2$ 3)$n=3$

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, i didn't notice the $dx$, I thought it was $dt$

Comment: No. I was right. There should be $dt$ in the last integral.

Comment: Sorry for not typing the whole thing, but you can do the following, for case $n=2$, take one of Euler substitution(look up in any calculus book, or in wikipedia), and than if necessary split any rational function you'll get into seperate simplier fractions. (Sometimes it is called Lagrange method of rational integrals). It may help, however I'm sorry, I tried a little, and then let it.

Comment: @kolobokish:Thank you for your reply.According to the Chebyshev's theorem, it can be expressed as an elementary function.But I have not yet calculated

Comment: For the case, $n=1$ it is obvious. For the case $n=2$, it can be done using Euler substitution.  Generally, in the kind of cases one mostly use trigonometric function to substitute something like $t=tgz$. But it would be helpful when you have $\sqrt{t^{2}+1}$, rather than $\sqrt{t^{2}-1}$. So Euler substitution, can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$t=(1+x^n)^{-1/n}\\dt=-\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^{-(n+1)/n}}dx\\t^{-n}=1+x^n\\x^{n-1}=(t^{-n}-1)^{(n-1)/n}\\x^{n-1}=\frac{(1-t^n)^{(n-1)/n}}{t^{n-1}}\\\int-\frac{t^{n-1}}{(1-t^n)^{(n-1)/n}}dt\\(1-t^n)^{1/n}=c\\-\frac{t^{n-1}}{(1-t^n)^{(n-1)/n}}dt=dc\\\int dc=c+C=(1-t^n)^{1/n}=(1-(1+x^n)^{-1})^{1/n}=(1-\frac{1}{1+x^n})^{1/n}=(\frac{x^n}{1+x^n})^{1/n}+C=x(1+x^n)^{-1/n}+C$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,I get it!

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to  $x{(1+x^n)}^{-1/n}+C$.

Comment: Could you explain how to get this formula?

Comment: Actually I take n=0,1,2 and get the result and then induct the final one.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Choose $x=1/y$

$\implies dx=-\dfrac{dy}{y^2}$

and $\dfrac1{(1+x^n)^{1+1/n}}=\dfrac{y^{n+1}}{(y^n+1)^{1+1/n}}$

Now set $y^n+1=u$

Or directly, $u=y^n+1=\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}$